# jQuery не ожидая ответа с сервера заканчивает работу

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Сразу же после отправления запроса на сервер, функция `ajax` завершает работу не дожидаясь ответа.

Как сделать так, чтобы в метод success заходило после получения ответа с сервера? При этом насколько я понимаю `async:` должен быть `true`, чтобы метод `createInProgress` продолжал работать и пользователь мог видеть линию прогресса.

`.js`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
        success: function (responce) {
            //сюда заходит
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function () {
            $('div#in_progress').remove();
        },
    };
    $("#getSityData").ajaxForm(options);
});

function executeOperation() {
    var url = "/getSityData",
        city = "Berlin";
    createInProgress('progressboxSityData');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {city: city},
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            //сюда не заходит
            $('div#in_progress').remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: а что собственно не так? он потому и async, что сразу отдает управление, а результат например в success обрабатывает, когда получает его

Comment: @Grundy ТС видимо интерпретирует `timeout` как параметр "сколько ничего не делать пока делается запрос"

Comment: Неужели канонического ответа по асинхронщине до сих пор нет?

Comment: @D-side, либо нет, либо они какие-то унылые все

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: `, а результат например в success обрабатывает, когда получает его – Grundy`
В том то й дело, что он переходит в success еще не получив ответа.

Comment: а что скажет `alert(responce)` ?

Comment: Перед вызовом функции `ajax` запускается метод - `createLoaderUpload('progressboxSityData');`. Этот метод создает полосу прогреса и пока запрос обрабатывается, клиент должен видеть эту полосу прогреса. И только после получения ответа управление должно перейти в success.


Но если `async: false`, метод `createLoaderUpload` не работает, соответственно полоса прогреса не показывается.

А если `async: true`, то полоса показывается на долю секунды так как управление сразу же переходит на success, где эта полоса удаляется.

Comment: @Giovanni, ну так правильно же все :-) судя по всему вы просто быстро получаете ответ от сервера :-) и логично, что после окончания запроса - нет смысла показывать прогресс

Comment: Добавляйте в вопрос больше кода и описания, что вы в действительности хотите сделать. В данном случае `$.ajax` работает именно так как и должен

Comment: Нет, ответ приходит где-то через 15-25 секунд.

Comment: @Giovanni, как засекали? если управление _зашло_ в метод _success_, то ответ _уже_ получен

Comment: @Grundy `как засекали?` - Смотрел в browser console.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38144/discussion-between-giovanni-and-grundy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно действительно проблема была в `ajaxForm`.
Но удалив `dataType: "json",` все заработало!
Хотя, как мне кажется это плохое решение, но в моем случае оно работающие:)

Comment: Скорее всего проблемма была в `<input type="submit">`. 
С прочитаного я понял что действие переходит на `success`так как для `submit` постоянно выполняет какие-то действия в браузере. Для отмены действий браузера нужно использовать event.preventDefault();

Также можно решить проблему использовать`button` вместо `submit`.